# Communication between Node.js microservices

Tags: node.js, microservices

I'm creating an application with Node.js using microservices architecture. I'm trying to find the best way of communication between nodes. I have a Java background so the best option I can imagine is something like SOAP, where you create a proxy object and by calling it's method a request to a remote node would be made via http.

Currently I only see an option of direct calls like

```
http.get("remote-node/api/method1", function(res) {
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

However I don't think it's convenient. Are there better approaches?

Thanks.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this - from something as simple as HTTP REST-ish calls between services, to something more advanced as a message bus oriented architecture. Message buses can make issues like service location and fault tolerance / retries easier. But I think the most important thing you can do is to abstract away communcation, so that you can replace it as your app grows - start with something simple and evolve.

Comment: As far as I read about microservices , using message bus is not recommended in this architecture. All nodes need to take care of their dependencies and messaging

Answer (score 2):

The most common and simple approach is to communicate between your microservices using a REST-ish approach. You will have to manually do the communication and the discovery of services, which can become messy as the system grows. You can also search for some packages on npm for service discovery and remote procedure calls.

I encourage the usage of [Studio](https://github.com/ericholiveira/studio) which is a microservices framework. It also has a plugin to do automatic clusterization (service discovery + rpc) with minimal configuration. This plugin also uses websockets for communication, which are more lightweight then REST-ish approach

Comment: Disclaimer: You seem to be the owner of the linked repo